# Can a development team containing both Windows and Mac users work together on a Flutter app?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, operating-system

I am in a team of 3 for a project. 2 of us are using Windows Laptops and 1 is using a Macbook. Would we be able to work together on a cross-platform mobile application for Android and iOS, using Flutter, Dart and Android Studio?

I've just pulled the first commit from the iOS programmer and it appears to be in C++ rather than dart under an 'ios' folder.

Comment: So your colleague is developing in the wrong language? Can you please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working in a project using exclusively Flutter/Dart. I'm on windows and the other two devs are on Mac. I haven't had any issues - I don't see why C++ code would appear if the developer is writing in dart.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's with the c++ code but most of your dart code resides in `lib/` folder. That's where you would be writing most of your code. 
The other programmer could have implemented some other functionality/module in c++ under the `ios/` folder of your project. This folder is specific to files necessary to configure and run your application on the IOS platform.